# How to change minimize button icon?

Tags: window-buttons

There are discussions on minimize button icon recently: since the launcher is on the left where minimized window goes, [should Ubuntu minimize button be vertical?](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/should-ubuntus-minimize-button-be-vertical?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20d0od%20%28OMG!%20Ubuntu!%29&utm_content=FaceBook) There are many different suggestions, such as a dot, an arrow, etc., but I think a single left-pointing arrow is the best.

Whether this is right or not, how to change minimize button to a left-pointing arrow?

Comment: Considering Ubuntu Touch right edge feature, which is similar to minimize an application, a left-pointing arrow for minimize button is meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, window button icons are defined through PNGs in **unity** and **metacity-1** folders in every theme, so replacing those PNGs easily results in changing the icons. If you are interested, I'll share my experience here.

You can find the default ones for *Ambiance* theme here:

`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/unity/`
`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/`

Since there are different modes for a window button, such as *prelight*, *pressed*, *focused*, you should have different shades for a single button; for example there are 7 PNGs in *unity* folder for different modes of minimize button. So I used GIMP to edit the default icons and make a new ones with a `‹` – Single Left-Pointing Angle Quotation Mark – and here's the result: [image: Single Left-pointing Arrow Minimize Button].

Now, if you want to change the minimize button to a single left-pointing arrow like this, download the PNGs created for **Ambiance** and **Radiance** themes [here](http://ubuntuone.com/6IA6GeQwb1lWQJfJaGfFij). Then extract the file and follow the procedure in *Read Me* file. I'm going to repeat it here:
Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these two commands (let assume that the extracted file is in *Downloads* directory):

```
cd Downloads/minimize-button

sudo cp -r Ambiance Radiance /usr/share/themes
```

[image: Screenshot for left-pointing minimize button]

---

(edit) If you don't want to change system files, or you are a user in a shared desktop and thus can't/don't want affect other users, you can download [this file](http://ubuntuone.com/6XiO8ZrtKyhREIWnIysgmg) instead. After you will extract the file, put two folders *Ambiance* and *Radiance* (or each you want) under the path:

**~/.themes/**

– if it doesn't exist, simply create it ("~" stands for your *home* folder as you may know).

This alternative doesn't need a root access.

### SVG’s for Unity 7 (14.04)

Supporting displays with higher resolutions, Unity 7 have **SVG**’s for window buttons. [This file](http://ubuntuone.com/6djZAI8Ykkp9W5lGmHzMLS) includes SVG’s of arrow minimize buttons for both **Ambiance** and **Radiance**. It includes buttons for Dash window too.

[image: Minimize SVG with single left-pointing arrow]

Comment: Download link no longer works

Comment: @EdVillegas, thanks for you mentioned. I've just corrected the link, and add an alternative as well.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for these, as I was, I made a set for the Radiance (white) theme. I uploaded them [here](http://photobucket.com/albums/z383/Gemneroth/Radiance%20minimize%20buttons/).

To use them, open a teminal and type: `gksu nautilus "/usr/share/themes/Radiance"`

then paste the 7 buttons into the folders `unity` and `metacity-1` then reboot and change the theme and back to radiance. That worked for me.

Comment: Well, there are also buttons for Radiance in my collection – if you look at the codes at the end of my answer, you can see both Ambiance and Radiance; it means it will replace buttons in both themes.